# Why is my Python Dictionary only returning the last value?

Tags: python, dictionary, raspberry-pi, rfid

I have an rfid reader which when scanned returns a UID as "backData"

I have my users (username and UID) stored in a text file.

I've managed to read the text file into a python dictionary, but when i scan my card, it is only accepting the last UID in the text file.

Text File:

```
164 168 124 90 42, user1
114 156 203 196 225, user2
```

Python Code:

```
for line in uid_file:
    info = line.split(",")
    key = info[0]
    uname = info[1]
    c = len(uname)-1
    uname = uname[0:c]
    uid_dict[key] = uname
    USER = [int(i) for i in key.split()]

    if backData == USER:
        f = open("/mnt/lock_logs/lock_log.csv", "a");
        print f
        value = ('\n') + uname
        myString = str(value)
        f.write(myString)
        f.close()
     else:
        print "Access Denied"
```

So if I scan the card assigned to user2, it works, but if I scan the card assigned to user1, I get Access Denied.

If i print the variable USER, it returns both UIDs from the text file.  Any ideas on what I need to change??

Comment: Please fix the indentation in the question to match the indentation in your code.

Comment: I don't understand what you are asking?

Comment: The indentation in your question is not legal in Python, so the indentation you're actually using must be different from the indentation in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this is because you continue to evaluate your for loop even after the user 1 is matched.  Add a 'break' to the bottom of your if statement.

```
if backData == USER:
    f = open("/mnt/lock_logs/lock_log.csv", "a");
    print f
    value = ('\n') + uname
    myString = str(value)
    f.write(myString)
    f.close()
    break
```

I recreated your file and am able to get predicted behavior with the following code.  Not that I hard coded backData and have tried it with both USER lists with success.

```
filename = 'uid.txt'

with open(filename) as uid_file:
    uid_dict={}

    backData = [164, 168, 124, 90, 42]
    no_matches = True

    for line in uid_file:
        info = line.split(",")
        key = info[0]
        uname = info[1]
        print info[0], info[1]
        c = len(uname)-1
        uname = uname[0:c]
        uid_dict[key] = uname
        USER = [int(i) for i in key.split()]

        if backData == USER:
            print "user matches"
            no_matches = False          
            break

    if no_matches:
        print "Access Denied"
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried it, but same result.  Also, with the break statement, my script ended after I scanned the second card. (like i pressed ctrl + c)

Comment: have you printed your backData variable to ensure it actually matches the USER list you are comparing it against?

Comment: I copied your code, but I keep getting an Indentation Line on the if statement??

Comment: Thank you, it is now working..  I had to add it all under the section for where the card is reading. previously I only had the backdata = User portion under their.

Comment: How do I move the else statement outside of loop?

Comment: Thank you. I tried your suggestion, but am still getting "Access Denied" printed each time it loops.

Answer (score -1):

Reanalyzing the code a bit, I am assuming that backData is an array, such as `[114, 156, 203, 196, 225]`.

Your code is going to loop through each line, checking the array against the stored key. It won't stop if it finds a match, and it will print Access Denied each time it doesn't match (not the same as if it had not found a match *at all*.)

A more detailed explanation:

If backData matched with user1, the following will happen in order:

1. Data for user1 is loaded.
2. backData is checked against the key for user1, matching.
3. `\nuser1` is appended to lock_log.csv
4. Data for user2 is loaded.
5. backData is checked against the key for user2, not matching.
6. `Access Denied` is printed.

If backData matched with user2, the following will happen in order:

1. Data for user1 is loaded.
2. backData is checked against the key for user1, not matching.
3. `Access Denied` is printed.
4. Data for user2 is loaded.
5. backData is checked against the key for user2, matching.
6. `\nuser2` is appended to lock_log.csv

If backData matched with neither, the following will happen in order:

1. Data for user1 is loaded.
2. backData is checked against the key for user1, not matching.
3. `Access Denied` is printed.
4. Data for user2 is loaded.
5. backData is checked against the key for user2, not matching.
6. `Access Denied` is printed again.

Comment: Sorry, i forgot to include this.. uid_dict = {}
uid_file = open('/home/pi/users.txt',"r")

Comment: Basically, I'm trying to store all my users in the text file, and if the scanned cards UID is equal to one in that text file, the username will be output to a csv file.

Comment: you are correct about backData.  Not sure what you mean, but if I scan the user2 card, it successfully writes the username to my csv file, if I scan user1 card, I get Access Denied.  If I print USER, both UIDs are printed

Comment: Can you double check the indentation on your post? I'm assuming the `if backData == USER:` line is at the same level as the `USER = [int(i) for i in key.split()]` line.

Comment: You are correct.  I apologize.  I fixed the indentation

Comment: I understand now, thank you, how do you suggest printing the Access Denied message.